# Google App maker drive picker attachments

Tags: google-app-maker

We have drive picker in app maker to upload files in google drive, but we have a requirement to upload files as attachment as we do in SharePoint.
Should we use Drive picker as attachment picker or do we need to write script to save files in fields.

Comment: How does SharePoint store attachments? By the way, storing files in model fields is definitely bad idea...

Comment: SharePoint will store data as base64 format. But if we store attachments in drive how we can present to the user in a form.

Comment: It depends on your design and requirements, the easiest way will be storing drive file URL or ID and showing user a link. You can go further and handle different file types individually(show previews for images, let users view documents in iFrames, show different icons, etc...).

Comment: Thank you pavel, I will try this method